Generalizations of a theorem of Edmonds/Tutte on existence of a perfect matching in a graphs
It is well known that for a bipartite graph $G$ with bi-adjacency matrix $A$, then $\det A \neq 0$ (as a polynomial) iff $G$ has a perfect matching (there is a similar result for general graphs with Tutte matrices).
I am looking references about generalizations of these results.
For instance: hypergraphs instead of graphs, triangle decomposition instead of perfect matching, some other variant of matching like 3-dim matching etc.
Ref: Edmond's Matrix, Tutte Matrix

You mean the bi-adjacency matrix whose nonzero entries are independent polynomial indeterminates?

@darijgrinberg yes

It is highly unlikely that such a generalization would exist, because the 3-dimensional matching problem is NP-complete, while polynomial identity testing can be solved efficiently using randomized algorithms.
